Remove soapcore xml response namespace
I have a soap service made with soapcore and .net 6 where the current response looks like this:
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <s:Body>
    <AuthRS DebitCard="false" OrderNumber="1398245417887881317988879319" ResponseCode="1" TransactionID="1207b292ae824" Version="2.8" xmlns="https://app.testurl.com.br">
      <RedirectURL>https://url.com.br/123123</RedirectURL>
    </AuthRS>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

I need the response to be sent without the xmlns="https://app.testurl.com.br".
I've already tried manipulating the response via MessageInspector, as I already do to remove the default SoapCore response node, but I always get the return with xmlns in the AuthRS tag.

The schema is required to do error checking.  It is easy to parse this xml with c# without removing important error checking.
